# What is longitudinal nature of Neutrino waves?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, optics, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, neutrinos

I was reading about the [Neutrino Theory of Light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_theory_of_light) (just for its learning value, I know it is not accepted that much these days), I came to a sentence in Wikipedia that was comparing light with neutrino and said:

> "Light's waves are transverse while Neutrino's waves are Longitudinal".

Does it mean Neutrinos move like sound waves?

Are they different from other particles in that way?

Comment: we now know neutrinos have a mass, and thus are not light like, as they have variable velocities. The probability of their existing at (x,y,z,t) has a sinusoidal nature.

Comment: It's not clear to me what this question is asking - what "longitudinal" and "transverse" mean you can easily search for. What *exactly* do you want to know about "neutrino waves"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind In my opinion, he thinks to sound waves in a neutrino gas. Or, to the QFT description of the neutrino field. My naive layman intuition says it is longitudinal in both cases.